# How to clone jQuery element with its data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can we clone jQuery elements with them data?

Using `.data("dummy", "test")` I set `"test"` data to `"dummy"` key of selected elements. Using `.data("dummy")` it returns `"test"`. After cloning `.data("dummy")` returns `undefined`.

How can I avoid this?

```
$(".save").on("click", function () {
    var dummy = $(this).data("dummy");
    if (dummy) {
        return alert(dummy);
    }

    $(this).data("dummy", "I am a button");
    var $clone = $(this).clone();
    $(this).after($clone);
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DEKFn/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were just missing 1 parameter...

http://jsfiddle.net/DEKFn/2/

Notice the use of `true` in the `clone()`.  That determines whether to copy data and events when cloning the element, as per the docs..

http://api.jquery.com/clone/

```
$(".save").on("click", function () {
    var dummy = $(this).data("dummy");
    if (dummy) {
        return alert(dummy);
    }

    $(this).data("dummy", "I am a button");
    var $clone = $(this).clone(true);
    $(this).after($clone);
});
```

You've also asked how to copy just the data - not the events.  This isn't possible, but you can remove all the event handlers like this...

```
    var $clone = $(this).clone(true);
    var $clone.off();
```

Comment: This copies the events also. Can I avoid that? I need only data. Anyway, this is the correct answer. ;-)

Comment: You can simply remove the events from the clone.  I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

clone takes an argument [withDataAndEvents](http://api.jquery.com/clone/#clone-withDataAndEvents) so do:

```
var $clone = $(this).clone(true);
```

to get only data just turn off the events.

```
var $clone = $(this).clone(true).off();
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MTAux/)**

Answer (score 0):

The data is attached to the element as a simple javascript object. Simply duplicate the data and assign it to the clone.

```
$(".save").on("click", function () { 
    var dummy = $(this).data("dummy");
    if (dummy) {
        return alert(dummy);
    }
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data("dummy", "I am a button");
    var $clone = $this.clone();
    var $data = $.extend(true,{},$this.data());
    $clone.data($data);
    $(this).after($clone);
});
```

More on .extend() http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/ 
Fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/9Q7EM/
EDIT:
Not sure why this was downvoted. You incur some overhead copying both the data and the events as the original answer suggested. Both are valid.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this. but this looks like not a bad option to me... so my +1..